# What private information is stored in a cache db wal file from android mobile device

Tags: privacy

I have just found a cache db wal file from android mobile device. I would like to know what private information of mine is stored in it. I did not make this file. Can I find out who made it?

Comment: What is the name of that file? Where did you find it?

Answer (score 2):

.db-wal file is a sql database write ahead log (wal) file. You can view more information on it here. 
[db-wal files](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html)

The sql database for whatever application it is made it, it is a normal file. you can use a file explorer such as x-plore on android and view contents, some of content may be encrypted some not.